# Drag and Drop images on Custom View

Tags: android, canvas, drag-and-drop, android-custom-view

I am planning to make and app in which I can drag and drop different types of ball images into a some sort of a field. To do so, I have made a simple example, in which I have examples of ball's images and I want to drag an drop multiple copies of it inside the field. This is the [example](http://s22.postimg.org/rtpf3hkwh/example.jpg) I've been doing some research and I've found that to do so, the best way is to have a customview object that will act as the field. It will contain a list of all the images I have and their positions in the field.

I am missing last step where I drop the image inside the customview and it is added inside the list of images it contains with it X and Y position so I am able to recover the image later with all its balls.

How can I do it? Here is the code I already have:

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LIST OF ITEMS TO DRAG"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ball"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_to_drag"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ball2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_to_drag2"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ball3"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_to_drag3"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CUSTOMVIEW WHERE DROP"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.dragandrop.canvas.canvas.Salon
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/salon_1"
        android:background="#96e29b"
        />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomView class

```
public class Field extends View
{
    Context context;

    public Salon(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Resources res = getResources();
        float left = 0;
        float top = 0;

    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView image;
    ImageView image2;
    ImageView image3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_drag);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_drag2);
        image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_drag3);

        image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(image);
                image.startDrag(clipData,shadowBuilder,image,0);

                return false;
            }
        });

        image2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(image2);
                image2.startDrag(clipData,shadowBuilder,image2,0);

                return false;
            }
        });

        image3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("","");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(image3);
                image3.startDrag(clipData,shadowBuilder,image3,0);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```